# Python - Create a data set with correlating numeric variables

Tags: python, random

I want to create a dataset where I have years of experience from 1 to 10 and have salary from 30k to 100k. I want these salaries to be random and to follow the years of experience. Sometimes a person with more experience may make less than a person with less experience.

For example:

```
years of experience | Salary
1                   | 30050
2                   | 28500
3                   | 36000
...
10                  | 100,500
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
years = np.linspace(1.0, 10.0, num=10)
salary = np.linspace(30000.0, 100000.0, num=10) + random.uniform(-1,1)*5000#plus/minus 5k
data = pd.DataFrame({'experience' : years, 'salary': salary})
print (data)
```

Which gives me:

```
   experience         salary
0         1.0   31060.903965
1         2.0   38838.681742
2         3.0   46616.459520
3         4.0   54394.237298
4         5.0   62172.015076
5         6.0   69949.792853
6         7.0   77727.570631
7         8.0   85505.348409
8         9.0   93283.126187
9        10.0  101060.903965
```

we can see that we do not get some records where a person with higher experience made less than a person with lower experience. How can I fix this? Of course I want to scale this to give me 1000 rows

Comment: You could increase the plus or minus 5k to a bigger value (15k maybe) and use random.normal instead of uniform so most will still end up with more money with more experience but some will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scikit-learn comes with some useful functions to generate correlated data, such as [`make_regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html#sklearn.datasets.make_regression).

You could for example do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

np.random.seed(0)
n_samples = 1000

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=1, n_informative=1, 
noise=80, random_state=0)

# Scale X (years of experience) to 0..10 range
X = np.interp(X, (X.min(), X.max()), (0, 10))

# Scale y (salary) to 30000..100000 range
y = np.interp(y, (y.min(), y.max()), (30000, 100000))

# To dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'experience': X.flatten(), 'salary': y}
print(df.head(10))
```

From what you describe, it seems as though you want to add some variance to the response. This can be done by adjusting the `noise` parameter. Let's plot it to make it more obvious:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(X, y, color='blue', marker='.', label='Salary')
plt.xlabel("Years of Experience")
plt.ylabel("Salary")
plt.show()
```

For example, using `noise=80`:
[image]

Or using `noise=250`:
[image]

As a side note: This generates continuous values for "years of experience". If you instead want them rounded to integers, you can do that using `X = np.rint(X)`

Answer (score 2):

You can define the salary to be equal to the number of years times some coefficient, plus some constant value, plus some random value.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
N = 1000
intercept = 30000
coeff = 7000
years = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=10, size=N)
salary = intercept + years*coeff + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10000, size=N)
data = pd.DataFrame({'experience' : years, 'salary': salary})
data.plot.scatter(x='experience', y='salary', alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would change the line:

```
salary = np.linspace(30000.0, 100000.0, num=10) + random.uniform(-1,1)*5000#plus/minus 5k
```

I think it is better to have the random section apart, in this way you can change that easly and make all your modification depending on the values you want to reach.

Here is something I did:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
years = np.linspace(1.0, 10.0, num=10)
random_list = [random.random()*1000*_*5 for _ in range(10)]
print(random_list)
salary = np.linspace(30000.0, 100000.0, num=10)- random_list
data = pd.DataFrame({'experience' : years, 'salary': salary})
print (data)
```

The random components has more variance, when the salary grows.

Answer (score 0):

`random.uniform(-1,1)*5000` means that your salary value will be changed by a range of -5k to +5k, but as uniform is continuous in its output, it could well be that the salary is changed by a very small amount.
seeing how the salary without the random element changes by 7777.77... per step up in experience, it is quite unlikely to get a lower salary for a higher experience. i would suggest you increase the factor behind your random element.
try `random.uniform(-1,1) * 10000` for example. how high you crank that randomness is up to you, depends on how likely it should be to get an overpaid inexperienced person.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
years = np.linspace(1.0, 10.0, num=10)
salary = np.random.randint(30000.0, 100000.0, 10)
data = pd.DataFrame({'experience' : years, 'salary': salary})
print (data)
```

Comment: all you have to do is just to use the random.randint function. i hope it works out for you

Comment: This doesn't work to make correlated data. it gives me random number between 30k and 100k. For example a person with 1 year of experience can make 100k and a person with 10 years can make 30k in your example. The salary should generally go up as experience goes up